# Qtip data not defined error

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, json, qtip2

I am using [Qtip](http://qtip2.com/) tooltip and my content is from JSON.
When i click the tooltip to display the content, i get an error that 'data is not defined' when inspecting the element in chrome.

This is my javascript code.

```
 $('#accordion_functions ul li a span:nth-child(2)').each(function () {    
  $(this).qtip({
        content: {
    text: function(event,api) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:51783/Help/GetHelpText.ashx', 
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json', 
           data: {
             id: $(this).attr('id') // Pass through the ID span
            },                  
        })
        .then(function(content) {

            var content = 'Help' + data.Text;                                
            api.set('content.text', content);

        }, function(xhr, status, error) {

            api.set('content.text', status + ': ' + error);
        });

        return 'Loading' // Set some initial loading text
    }
},
        hide: {
            event: 'click',
            fixed: true,
            delay: 50
        },
        show: {
            event: 'click',
            solo: true
        },
        events: {
            show: function (event, api) {
                $(api.elements.target).addClass('highlight');
            },
            hide: function (event, api) {
                $(api.elements.target).removeClass('highlight');
            }
        },
        style: {                
            width: 1200,
            padding: 5,
            tip: 'bottomRight',
        },
        position: {
            my: 'bottom right',
            at: 'bottom middle'
        }
    });
```

The data posted by the url looks like this:

```
[{"id":"PCG01","Form":"Party Company","Tab":"General","Text":"Help needed here"},{"id":"PCG02","Form":"Party Company","Tab":"Contact","Text":"This is a second help"},{"id":"PCG03","Form":"Party Company","Tab":"Settlement","Text":"Third help"},{"id":"PCG04","Form":"Party Company","Tab":"Client","Text":"Fourth help"},{"id":"PCG05","Form":"Party Company","Tab":"Trade Constraints","Text":"Fifth help"},{"id":"PCG06","Form":"Party Company","Tab":"Attachments","Text":"Sixth help"}]
```

What could i be doing wrong?

Comment: Why don't you make an ajax query first and then configure our qTip?

Comment: How do i do that? Could my problem be the [ ] ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

isn't it in the `.then`

```
    .then(function(content) {

        var **contentText** = 'Help' + **content**.Text;                                
        api.set('content.text', **contentText**);
```

Comment: Just tried your suggestion and it returns 'Help undefined', meaning that it does not capture the json data well.

Comment: indeed, either content is undefined or it doesn't contain a property Text, but you have something to work with now :)

Comment: I agree with you and thanks. Text is actually one of the objects in the json data or should i change the name?

Comment: `content` is the response your service sends back. As per your code, I assume it should have a property `Text`. Have a look at chrome `F12` debugging tools, tab network to see the request/response and inspect its content

Comment: Yes, `content` is what should be send back, `Text` is the field name in the json data. So i want `content` to send back the value contained in the field name called `Text`.

Comment: Could it be that your service sends back an array? Could you try `content[0].Text` ?

Comment: I figured out the problem. The problem was how i were accessing my json objects. I have posted the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the  `.then`. I were basically accessing the json object in a wrong way.

I changed `.then` from:

```
.then(function(content) {
        var content = 'Help' + data.Text;                                
        api.set('content.text', content);
    },
```

To:

```
.then(function(content) {                
            var content = 'Help' + content[0].Text +'';                                                
            api.set('content.text', content);
        },
```

Comment: This is what @Skyp said exactly. Accept his answer since it was the correct one in stead of copying what someone said and stuff...

Comment: I edited @Skyp's answer and accepted it. I wouldn't accept it while it is still incorrect.